# Batch For /f variable with minus parameters doesn't work for me

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Inside the %list% txt file there are multiple paths and inside %List2Backup% there are multiple files list only, I need to copy each file to each server name location based on first server name only
example of location from %list%

```
\\TestServer1\D$\Location1\Drafts\Testings\1\2\3
\\TestServer2\C$\Location1\Drafts\Testings\1\2\3
```

I want files to be copied to

```
"%~dp0\BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\TestServer1\filename.dll
```

This is the current code which copy the files but within multiple folders like

```
"%~dp0\BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\TestServer1\D$\Location1\Drafts\Testings\1\2\3\
"%~dp0\BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\TestServer2\C$\Location1\Drafts\Testings\1\2\3\
```

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %G% in (%list%) do ( for /f "tokens=* usebackq delims=" %J% in 
("%List2Backup%") do (xcopy /f /y /r "%G%%J%" "%~dp0\BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\%G%"))
```

Comment: It looks like the command line to use in the batch file for this file copying task is: `for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0%list%") do for /F "eol=| delims=\" %%J in ("%%I") do for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=\" %%# in ("%%~dp0List2Backup%") do if exist "%%I\%%#" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I\%%#" "%~dp0BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\%%J\" /F /R /Y >nul`

Comment: Mofi thanks I managed to make it work this way: `for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%list%") do for /F "eol=| delims=\" %%J in ("%%I") do for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=\" %%# in ("%List2Backup%") do if exist "%%I\%%#" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%I\%%#" "%~dp0BackupDlls_%Environment%_%format:~-0,30%\%%J\" /F /R /Y` . What are eol=| means? also delims=\ please